# OpenXML：The value of shape offset is clearly abnormal

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

A few shapes have values that seem to be incorrect.
The test file link：
[file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A6y7o8xwEWPXXihI9KTQoshPT2oVeRKK/view?usp=drive_link)
For example, the shape with name "s-4-4" in the attached file "test1.pptx", after unzipping the ppt, you can see that its x="7676320" y="-2309191", which is converted to pixel is (805, -242), no matter it's x or y, the logic is totally different from other shapes!

Problem Analysis:
According to the analysis of the available information, I think: the value of offset, is the value of the coordinates of the upper left corner  of the bounding box.
The coordinate value of the PPT canvas is (0,0) for the upper left corner, x value increases to the right, y value increases to the bottom.
In the test1.pptx file, all elements fulfill this logic, with the exception of s-4-4.

Regarding x and y, the documentation says "Specifies a coordinate on the x-axis. The origin point for this coordinate shall be specified by the parent XML element. "
My guess is that the parent element has a datum coordinate, or that some shapes are not positioned according to the top-left coordinate.
But as you can see in the attachment, the shape with name "s-5-5" is very similar to "s-4-4" with type "ShapeTypeValues. RightTriangle", but the offset of "s-5-5" is x="7354957" y="1", which is perfectly cognizant of the fact that s-4-4 baffles me.

[image1 is screenshot of s-4-4][1]

[image2 is screenshot of s-5-5][2]

[image3 is converted to pixel coordinates][3]

[image4 is Raw xml for s-4-4][4]

[enter link description here][5]

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LOIO.png   [2]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/9heCs.png   [3]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsEwu.png   [4]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6nxn.png   [5]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJHAl.png

Comment: Just a vague recollection that might be incorrect, but ISTR that the XML coordinate system from PPT starts in the center of the slide, with positions to left/above center expressed as negative numbers. Does that fit with what you're seeing?

Comment: That was my guess at first, but in "test1.pptx", all the shapes are positioned from the top left corner, and there are no negative values in either the top left or top right corner of the shape. They are all positive values.
Only the "s-4-4" has a strange and obviously incorrect negative value. Even with the center of the canvas at (0,0), its x-value is significantly wrong.
I've updated the problem statement to add a couple of screenshots
Can you help me with the screenshots, or can you download the test file at the url： https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A6y7o8xwEWPXXihI9KTQoshPT2oVeRKK/view

Comment: The strange thing about this is that all the other shapes can be explained by "the upper left corner is (0,0)", but only this one can't be explained.
Also, wherever (0,0) is, it doesn't make sense because its x-value isn't normal either!

Comment: I suspect that you're seeing odd results because the original shape is rotated 270 degrees. Set its rotation back to 0 to see what I *think* are the coordinates that PPT is storing. In points, top = -181.8261 and left = 604.4346. And converted to pixels, assuming 96dpi, you get exactly the same values as you mention above.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
It's because of the rotation.
The coordinates in the xml are not the actual coordinates displayed on the canvas, they are the coordinates before rotation
It's not intuitive, but it's true.